# How to convert number from one number range to another number range with Arduino

Tags: math, numbers, arduino

I am using an ultrasonic proximity sensor to get how close an object is. If the object is equal to or less than 50cm away from the sensor, it will convert the number (between 0-50) to a number between 0-255 so it can be used to change an LED brightness.

How can I convert the number from one range to another in my code?

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Ps. Please don't flag this as a clone – I tried to find a question like this but none of them met the right criteria...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
brightness = distance <= 50 ? distance * 255 / 50 : 255;
```

Reading between the lines though I suspect you want the brightness to *increase* as the distance *decreases*, so you probably want something more like this:

```
brightness = distance < 50 ? (50 - distance) * 255 / 50 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much – this worked perfectly! Sorry, I should have specified I wanted it to go up the closer the object was. The only question I have is, what do the ? and : signs do? I'm just a beginner at Arduino so I don't really understand the code.

Comment: `?:` is a conditional operator which is often used as shorthand for an `if/else` assignment, so for example `z = x < y ? x : y;` is equivalent to `if (x < y) z = x; else z = y;`.